# How to Calculate the Sum of a Column with multipliers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made a Trigger for a table that basically sums up the total price for a certain ID and Update another table After any change . 
Now I need to count in different currencies and each has its own value and I got the CurrencyID and it's Value from another table . 
I need to Multiply each updated price with the value of its currency and sum up the whole price . Can somebody help me with this please ?

the Trigger by itself works fine without currencies and I've already looked up the "X*Y=EXP(LN(X)+LN(Y))" formula . I'm thinking about gathering all the  Prices and Currency multipliers in new table and multiply the rows , but I don't know how to do it or how to use the formula !

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [CMS].[HoldingSum]
   ON  [CMS].[PartOfOneHoldingADeal]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @ChangedDataID uniqueidentifier;
    if exists (select * from inserted)  SET @ChangedDataID = (Select Top 1 inserted.IDHoldingADeal from inserted);
    else if exists (select * from deleted)  SET @ChangedDataID = (Select Top 1 deleted.IDHoldingADeal from deleted);

    UPDATE CMS.HoldingADeal
    SET PriceHoldingADeal = (Select Sum(PricePartOfOneHoldingADeal) total
            from CMS.PartOfOneHoldingADeal
             where PartOfOneHoldingADeal.IDHoldingADeal=@ChangedDataID)
    where HoldingADeal.IDHoldingADeal = @ChangedDataID;
END
```

I expect the out to be one total price (probably a bigint) that I'm want to Update my table with .

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your trigger is just totally broken.  You are assuming that `inserted` and `deleted` have only one row, but that is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you want to use, it's used if you want to make a product between values in different rows. So in your case it does not apply. You need to make for each row a conversion to a base currency (?) and update the field.

So in your case (without knowing your schema), I would say something like:

```
UPDATE CMS.HoldingADeal
    SET PriceHoldingADeal = (Select Sum(PricePartOfOneHoldingADeal * c.rate) total
            from CMS.PartOfOneHoldingADeal p
            join currencies c
                on p.currencyId = c.id
            where PartOfOneHoldingADeal.IDHoldingADeal=@ChangedDataID)
    where HoldingADeal.IDHoldingADeal = @ChangedDataID;
```

Considering that you have a rate column that translates to your base currency. You can tinker around with it in case your currency table is different. Also you need to make sure that you have all the currencies there otherwise the query will fail.

If you consider not to have the base currency there, then make a left join instead of a join and add an isnull to your value

```
isnull(PricePartOfOneHoldingADeal * c.rate,PricePartOfOneHoldingADeal)
```